# add default keys in output for missing node object - jolt transform

Tags: java, json, apache-nifi, jolt

My **Input** request payload is as below:

```json
{
  "attributes": {
    "training": {
      "attr1": "somevalue",
      "attr2": "somevalue"
    },
    "services": [
      {
        "recommendedService": "medical",
        "providedOrInitiated": 1
      },
      {
        "recommendedService": "engineering",
        "providedOrInitiated": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My **desired output** payload should be like:

```json
{
  "attributes": {
    "training": { // Transform node if received in request
      "training1": "somevalue",
      "training2": "somevalue"
    },
    "services": { // Transform node if received in request
      "medicalProvided": 1,
      "engineeringProvided": 0,
      "caProvided": 0, // If not received in request, set to 0 for all missing keys
      "doctorProvided": 0,
      "teacherProvided": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my **json transformation spec**:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "attributes": {
        "ParentID": "customAttributesMap.ParentID",
        "training": {
          "attr1": "attributes.training.training1",
          "attr2": "attributes.training.training2"
        },
        "services": {
          "*": {
            "recommendedService": {
              "medical": {
                "@(2,providedOrInitiated)": "attributes.services.medicalProvided"
              },
              "engineering": {
                "@(2,providedOrInitiated)": "attributes.services.engineeringProvided"
              }
// How to set default for missing input fields.
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }
]
```

I tried with **default** operation, but it adds keys even if **services** node is not received in request. That should not happen. Requirement is like transform node whichever is present in request. And only that should be sent in output. That's why default operation is not useful here.

Overall requirement is like Inside "service" node

```
{
   "recommendedService": "<SERVICE_NAME>",
   "providedOrInitiated": 1 // value 1 or 0
}
```

e.g. "medical" service is present then map *medicalProvided* to beneath *providedOrInitiated* value otherwise set it as 0.

All the nodes are dynamic. They might present or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "servicesTemp": {
          "medical": 0,
          "engineering": 0,
          "caProvided": 0,
          "doctor": 0,
          "teacher": 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&1.&",
        "services": {
          "*": {
            "providedOrInitiated": "&3.&2.@(1,recommendedService)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&1.&",
        "services": {
          "*": "&2.services.&",
          "@(1,servicesTemp)": "&2.services"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "services": {
          "*": "=lastElement"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*Temp": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks. This very much work with provided input. But thing is there are 5 services: medical, engineering, ca, doctor and teacher. Map it to its providedOrInitiated field value. If it is not present then set to 0.

Comment: Hi Mohammad, `"=toInteger(0)"` seems superfluous, just use a single `0` ...

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Right, But the output value has an `integer` type.

Comment: `0` is already an integer ...

Comment: @MohammadReza. thanks for updated answer. But still need some modification.
Consider Input request does not contain "service" object at all, but still it will populate "service" node in output. That should not happen. 
Transform object only if it is received.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I check it again. When we use it like `"=toInteger(0)"` it's an `integer` and when use as `"0"` it's a `string`.

Comment: Well, What differs if you replace `"caProvided": "=toInteger(0)"` with `"caProvided": 0` within the current solution ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Please see this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEEbZ.png

Comment: no need to quote the value of medical, eg. just use `medical=0`

Answer (score 1):

You can consecutively use **shift** and **modify** transformations such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "attributes": {
        "training": {
          "attr*": "&2.&1.&1&(0,1)"
        },
        "services": {
          "*": {
            "@providedOrInitiated": "&3.&2.@recommendedService",
            "$": "&3.&2.medical",
            "#0": "&3.&2.engineering",
            "#00": "&3.&2.ca",
            "#000": "&3.&2.doctor",
            "#0000": "&3.&2.teacher"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "services": {
          "*": "=max" // the function returns the integer result, and that won't be the default(`0`) if really returned a value which's `1` 
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: If "service" object is not received in request, then it should not be displayed in output. "default" operation will override that behaviour. That's why it is not useful

Comment: **@Barbaros Özhan** You are getting just the first index of the `services` array. So if the `engineering providedOrInitiated` value was `1` you can't cover it.

Comment: good catch ! Just fixed @MohammadReza